# antD configProvider not recognizing theme prop

Tags: antd

I have followed the documentation from antD for setting the custom theme using ConfigProvider. https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme.

However, in implementation the theme prop is not recognized.
[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zdxB.png)

I updated the pankod/refine-antd package but still not recognized. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out new version of @pankod/refine-antd has just been created. Update to version 4.7.0 and issue is resolved.